# I have a error with tiptip jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip

In my example the Tiptip jquery not works, why?
I import the Jquery, the Css and i make the script.

Link: http://www.lookcommunication.it/testalessio/

Thanks for help.

Comment: Show the code. No one can help you without your code.

Comment: Get Firebug and learn to watch your console for errors.  You're not getting jQuery loaded before tiptip on your site, and therfore your tiptip file is throwing an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the plugin after jQuery. Also, use the latest version.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.tipTip.minified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```